# How to hide Div tags according to device size changes in Materializecss?

Tags: css, materialize

When it comes to the desktop view, the interface should be of 3 column. But when it comes to the mobile view (360 x 640) or (360 x 480), I don't want to display the first column, only two columns should be displayed.
For reference, here I've mentioned three columns.

```
<div class="col s12 m2 l2">...</div>
<div class="col s12 m8 l8">...</div>
<div class="col s12 m2 l2">...</div>
```

Comment: Use the `.hidden-xs` class on the column you don't want.

Comment: `.hidden-xs` doesn't work.

Comment: Can you provide a little more detail on the code you're using?

Comment: `hide-on-small-and-down` worked! Anyways thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

@media indirectly helped me and let me tell you how. As the details mentioned in the above answer, I searched @media in the existing CSS. I found the properties like `hide-on-small-and-down`, `hide-on-med-and-down` and so on. I applied those on div classes and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

you can redefine css properties under:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {

}
```

for instance:

```
.btn{
     display: none;
}

    @media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
    .btn {
        display: inline;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Alex, it helped me indirectly.